# Does anyone have a solution to this layout issue in IE?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Below is the link to the layout issue. Does anyone know why it shows up like that in IE and the fix for it? i.e. why does the textbox go beyond the outer div? It is fine in both Chrome & Firefox.

http://nothing123.s3.amazonaws.com/test-ie.htm

Here is the html.

```
<style>
  #loginBox {
    width: 336px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  #loginEmail {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<div id="loginBox">
  <input type="text" id="loginEmail"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has everything to do with the box model.

The actual `#loginBox` actual width is equal to the width + paddings + border. Your loginBox is now 348px (336+(5x2)+(1x2)):

Now `#loginEmail` is set to 100% relative to it's parent width, which would be 348px. Now add it's padding and it's border, it becomes 360px. Since the inner part of `#loginBox` is only 336px, naturally it bleeds out.

a quick remedy is to add `box-sizing:border-box` to `#loginEmail` so it won't bleed out (so that it takes into account the border and padding in it's 100%). However, this is only supported in IE8+.

For more info about this property and what browsers support it, [check this page](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing)

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have added width 100% alongwith padding 5px to #loginEmail. The padding:5px adds up the width which then becomes more than 100% and hence it is bleeding out of the div.
To solve this issue, either you specify the width in px or padding in percentage. e.g

```
#loginEmail {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 1%;/*total 2% for left(1%) and right(1%) padding*/
    width: 97%;/*97 + 2%(padding) = 99%*/
  }

OR

#loginEmail {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
  }
```

Comment: Even this works, but I found box-sizing style to be an easy fix. Thanks.

Comment: yes it will work but its not compatible with IE<8 browsers. Read this for more info http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Answer (score 0):

adding this css style to the #loginEmail fixes the problem

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because of #loginEmail padding 5px. Remove it and use padding top + bottom. and use text-indent:5px to move text to 5x left;